# PHP - Converter XML para Objeto

Tags: php, xml, classes, objetos

Existe uma forma com PHP de transfomar um XML em um objeto e objeto em xml? 
Exemplo:

```
** Classe (objeto) **

<?php
class Telefone {
  private $codigoArea;
  private $numero;

  public function setCodigoArea($codigoArea) {
      $this->codigoArea = $codigoArea;
  }

  public function getCodigoArea(){
      return $this->codigoArea;
  }

  public function setNumero($numero) {
      $this->numero = $numero;
  }

  public function getNumero(){
      return $this->numero;
  }
}
?>

** XML **

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<telefone>
   <codigoArea></codigoArea>
   <numero></numero>
</telefone>


** Exemplo do que preciso: **

$fone = new Telefone();
$xml = algumMetodoFuncao($fone); --> Algum metodo/função que transforme meu objeto em XML (O $fone não é uma string)
```

Comment: Deu certo minha resposta?

Comment: Certinho... É  isso mesmo... Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei uma classe estática chamada `XMLobject` para fazer isso. Nela tem 2 funções:

- **gerarXML()** : Recebe um objeto e cria um arquivo no diretório selecionado
- **gerarObjeto()** : Recebe um arquivo xml e gera o objeto com os parâmetros dentro do arquivo

Para essas funções funcionarem, algumas regras tem que ser seguidas.

**gerarXML()**

*Todo o elemento xml só pode ser gerado se houver um getter publico do atributo.* Isso significa que se você quiser gerar um elemento `<nome>` no xml, a classe do seu objeto deverá conter um `getNome()`.

**gerarObjeto()**

*A classe do objeto que será criado deverá ser incluída antes de chamar este método.* Caso contrário irá gerar um erro. Além disso, todo o elemento do xml precisa de um setter na classe. Isso significa que se você tem um elemento `<sobrenome>` no xml é necessário um `setSobrenome()` na classe.

**Classe XMLobject**

```
class XMLobject {

    static function gerarXML($objeto, $dir =""){

        $class = get_class ($objeto);
        $methods = get_class_methods ($class);
        $atributos = [];
        $functions = [];

        // recupera os atributos através dos metodos
        foreach($methods as $key => $method){
            if(strpos($method, "get") !== false && strpos($method, "get") === 0){
                $atributos[] = lcfirst(substr($method,3,strlen($method) -1));
                $functions[] = $method;
            }
        }

        // cria o xml com os valores dos geters
        $stringXML  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
        $stringXML .= '<'.$class.'>';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($atributos); $i++){
            $function = $functions[$i];
            $stringXML .= '<'.$atributos[$i].'>'.$objeto->$function().'</'.$atributos[$i].'>';
        }
        $stringXML .= '</'.$class.'>';

        // gera o arquivo no diretorio informado
        file_put_contents($dir.$class.".xml",$stringXML);
    }

    static function gerarObjeto($xml_uri){
        // pega todos os elementos do arquivo xml
        $content = file_get_contents($xml_uri);
        preg_match_all('/<[\w\s\d\\"\'\.]+[^\/]>[\w\d]*/', $content, $elementos);
        $obj = null;
        foreach($elementos[0] as $key => $elemento){    
            $valores = explode(">", $elemento);
            $atributo = substr($valores[0],1, strlen($valores[0]));
            if($key == 0) {
                // gera a classe
                $obj = new $atributo();
                continue;
            }
            if(is_object($obj)){
                // insere os valores nos atributos do objeto
                $method = "set".ucfirst($atributo);
                $obj-> $method($valores[1]);
            }
        }
        return $obj;
    }

}
```

---

### **Exemplo de Uso:**

***Gerando um xml***

```
$telefone = new Telefone();
$telefone -> setNumero("9999999999");
$telefone -> setCodigoArea("11");
XMLobject::gerarXML($telefone);
```

Resultado: (arquivo: Telefone.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Telefone>
        <codigoArea>11</codigoArea>
        <numero>9999999999</numero>
    </Telefone>
```

---

***Gerando um Objeto***

```
$obj = XMLobject::gerarObjeto("Telefone.xml");
print_r($obj);
```

Resultado:

```
Telefone Object ( [codigoArea:Telefone:private] => 11
[numero:Telefone:private] => 9999999999 )
```

Comment: Perfeito... é isso mesmo que preciso... Muito obrigado

Comment: @Mamga que bom que deu certo. =) qualquer dúvida pode me chamar!

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

Comment: Não tenho um XML/String... neste caso como ficaria  $xml = simplexml_load_string( ??? ); ? OBrigado

Comment: no manual do PHP tem um exemplo. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Sim o simplexml-load-string eu tinha visto, mas pelo que entendi nao atende o que preciso... Fiz uma correção na minha pergunta. Agora tenho um exemplo do que preciso. Obrigado